# Bitmap and handle memory leak

Tags: c#, bitmap, handle

I'm developing a simple C# winform application.
I create a bitmap and get a bitmap handle.
And use bitmap handle.

At that time, when I dispose bitmap, is bitmap handle free memory?
And when I free memory handle using DeleteObject method, is bitmap dispose?

Thanks in advice.

-----------EDIT------------

```
int prevCookie = 0;
private void testMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        //Draw some shapes on bitmap
    }
    int hBitmap = bmp.GetHBitmap().ToInt32();
    //I used intel media sdk library.
    int newCookie;
    intelMediaSdkVariable.AddImageFromHandle(hBitmap, out newCookie);
    if (prevCookie > 0)
        intelMediaSdkVariable.RemoveItem2(prevCookie);
    prevCookie = newCookie;
    bmp.Dispose();
}
```

At that time, when I call testMethod for 1000 times, memory increases.
When I call bmp.Dispose(), is hBitmap free?
How can I fix it?

Comment: Maybe.  Depends on the code

Comment: Plutonix you should post it as an answer :)

Comment: We need to see _how_ are you creating the bitmap for example.  For all we know you are using p-invoke.  _"I create a bitmap and get a bitmap handle"_ worries me

Comment: @MickyD it is possible to get [handle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4(v=vs.110).aspx) of a bitmap in managed code.

Comment: It is normal if memory increase. You should test with more times, perphap 10000. If from specific time, the memory almost doesn't increase, then you can say that there is no memory leak.

Comment: @Sakura I'm aware. Prior to the poster posting any code this question was far too unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to delete `hBitmap` handle.

```
int prevCookie = 0;
private void testMethod(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(100, 100);
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
    {
        //Draw some shapes on bitmap
    }
    int hBitmap = bmp.GetHBitmap().ToInt32();
    //I used intel media sdk library.
    int newCookie;
    intelMediaSdkVariable.AddImageFromHandle(hBitmap, out newCookie);
    if (prevCookie > 0)
        intelMediaSdkVariable.RemoveItem2(prevCookie);
    prevCookie = newCookie;
    DeleteObject((IntPtr)hBitmap);   // <---------- You dont have this line.
    bmp.Dispose();
}

[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObject);
```

I don't use Intel media sdk library, so I can not say if bellow code have memory leak or not:

```
int newCookie;
intelMediaSdkVariable.AddImageFromHandle(hBitmap, out newCookie);
if (prevCookie > 0)
    intelMediaSdkVariable.RemoveItem2(prevCookie);
prevCookie = newCookie;
```

Comment: You mean delete handle and dispose bitmap at the same time.
dispose bitmap not release handle memory. right?

Comment: [GetHBitmap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1dz311e4(v=vs.110).aspx) create new object, so `bmp` & `hBitmap` are two different objects. Your code only dispose one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.